# Does reduceness of $K[t_1,\dots,t_n]/I$ imply radicality of $I$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Let $I$ be an ideal in $K[t_1,\dots,t_n]$. Is it true that if the quotient $K[t_1,\dots,t_n]/I$ is reduced then $I$ is radical?

We say that a ring $R$ is *reduced* if $x^2 = 0$ implies $x=0$ for all $x \in R$.  If $a \in \sqrt{I}$ then $\exists k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $a^k \in I$, so $\overline{a^k} = \overline{a}^k = 0$ in the quotient.  Now I don't know how to use the reducedness, which tells me that $\overline{a}^2 = 0$ implies $\overline{a} = 0$.

Comment: What have you tried?  This seems to follow immediately from the definition of reduced and the radical of an ideal.

Comment: If $a\in\sqrt{I}$ then $\exists k\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $a^k\in I$, so $\overline{a^k}=\overline{a}^k=0$ in the quotient. Now I don't know how to use the reduceness, which tells me that $\overline{a}^2=0$ implies $\overline{a}=0$.

Comment: Ah okay, my definition of reduced is exactly that there are no nonzero nilpotent elements.  I'll post a hint.

Comment: I searched and found that the most common definition is yours. I don't know if they are equivalent. Anyway this soves my problem.

Comment: I've posted a proof showing that the two definitions of reduced are equivalent.  By the way, please include your definitions in the problem statement---you see how important it is now!

Answer (score 3):

Here's a useful lemma to get you started:

*Lemma*: Let $R$ be a ring.  Suppose that $R$ is reduced, i.e., that $x^2 = 0 \implies x=0$ for all $x \in R$.  Then $R$ has no nonzero nilpotent elements.

*Proof*: Suppose $x^k = 0$.  We claim $x = 0$.  If $k = 2^m$ is a power of $2$, then the claim follows easily by induction: $0 = x^{2^m} = \left(x^{2^{m-1}}\right)^2$ implies $x^{2^{m-1}} = 0$.  (For example, if $k = 4$, then
$$
0 = x^4 = (x^2)^2 \implies x^2 = 0 \implies x=0
$$
and this works similarly for any power of $2$.)

For $k$ not (necessarily) a power of $2$, choose $m$ large enough so that $2^m > k$.  Multiplying the equation $0 = x^k$ by $x^{2^m - k}$, we have $0 = x^{2^m}$.  Then $x = 0$ by the special case considered above. $\square$

Okay, now that we see that reduced $\implies$ no nonzero nilpotents, do you see how to complete the problem?